# WebService Debug Synchronization (why do my breakpoints give the message "The source code is different from the original version"?)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-services

I'm fairly new to web service development, and I am really confused about how ASP.Net Development Server synchronizes with code during debug mode.    When I make changes to my service, I cannot figure out how to propigate those changes so that my client can "see" them (I've been able to synchronize through a stumbling series of publishing the service, viewing the service in browser, etc... but I have a feeling there's a more reliable system than my random ritual).

Here are the symptoms I'm seeing:  After I've made a change to the code behind my service (Service1.svc.cs), started the application through the debugger and attached the debugger to the WebDev.WebServer.exe process as well, my latest changes are not executed, and my breakpoints are not hit (they have the message that 
"The source code is different from the original version."

What really baffles me, though, is that when the ASP.Net Development Server notification pops up in my system tray, its physical path points to my project folder, so I don't understand how it could be looking at anything *but* my current code files.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like to play with knives but the only thing that worked for me involves editing the .csproj file itself. So, unload the project file, edit it by cutting and pasting the three asp.net files so that they are together in the ItemGroup. However, sometimes it is necessary to go further as explained here: http://carnotaurus.tumblr.com/post/4130422114/visual-studio-debugging-issue-with-files-of-the-same - Also, I give a list of other proposed solutions that did not work for me. I hope it helps.